# Canvas (Zebra UI) & Internet Explorer 11 with Surface Pro 3 on Windows 8.1

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, surface, zebra-ui-framework

I'm developing a web application and decided to use Zebra UI. http://www.zebkit.com

Using an all canvas application has almost nearly surpassed my web developer dreams of making a cross-browser application that doesn't rely on hacks to account for differences between browsers. That is, until Microsoft.

Using a Surface Pro 3 tablet, Windows 8.1 and Internet Explorer 11, I've found some odd behaviors.

1. In IE=Edge the Canvas simply does not respond. Why might this be when this mode works for IE on standard PCs Win7/8.1 but not on the Surface?
2. In IE=9 the Canvas elements work, but HTML5 things like the FileReader API are not useable which I rely upon heavily. Zebra UI actually suggests IE=9 which boggles me, why use an old spec like that? Is there a way I can use LocalStorage, and FileReader API while in IE=9 mode?
3. In Chrome the Stylus seems to behave differently that finger touches, just found that odd, any explanation?

Have you experienced anything similar while working with Surface Pro?

Answer (score 0):

According to [zebkit](http://www.zebkit.com/question/meta-ieedge-vs-ie9/), IE Edge isn't properly supported yet and a dev version is being prepared to hopefully fix this issue.

Comment: yes.. that thread is my question actually.. this question however is about canvas / surface pro more in general, beyond just Zebra...